# Вставить переменную, чтобы получить путь к элементу объекта

Tags: javascript, json

Суть вопроса такова:
Есть объект

```js
state: {
  newAdv: {
    titleAdv: '',
    linkAdv: '',
    imgAdv: ''
  }
}
```

и есть функция, которая вставляет данные из ивента:

```js
export function onChangePost(event) {
    let nameEvent = event.name 
    state.newAdv.titleAdv = event.value

}
```

Как можно на место titleAdv поставить переменную nameEvent, чтобы она динамически подставлялась в путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
state.newAdv[nameEvent]
```